# Capture short host name using built-in Perl modules?

Tags: perl

Is there a cleaner way to do

```
use Sys::Hostname qw(hostname);

my $hostname = hostname();
$hostname =~ s/\.domain//;
```

Basically, is it possible to strip the hostname down to its short name without running two `$hostname` assignments and without additional modules?

Comment: You are only doing one assignment to `$hostname`. The second line is not an assignment. You are operating on the variable. Why do you care?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use [`Net::Domain`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Domain.html)'s `hostname` instead

> Returns the smallest part of the FQDN which can be used to identify the host.

```
use Net::Domain qw(hostname);
my $hostname = hostname();
```

---

Without additional modules, call external command [`hostname -s`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hostname.1.html)

> -s, --short
>   Display the short host name. This is the host name cut at the
>   first dot.

```
chomp(my $hostname = `hostname -s`);
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `Sys::Hostname`:

```
use Sys::Hostname;

my ($short_hostname) = split /\./, hostname(); # Split by '.', keep the first part
```

Using system hostname command:

```
chomp(my ($short_hostname) = `hostname | cut -f 1 -d.`);
```